# Kendo ui grid checkbox field binding

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-grid

I´ve seen other posts regarding to checkboxes on the grid, but i didn´t find anything related to my problem, so, i have some fields on my grid that i want to use as checkboxes, and i have declared them like this:

```
fields: 
{
 cloud: {type: "boolean"},

columns: 
[
{ field:"cloud",title:"Cloud",width:"1.5%",template:"<input type='checkbox' name='cloud' data-bind='#= cloud#' checked='#= cloud #' disabled='disabled'></input>",headerAttributes:{style:"font-size: 11px;text-align:center;"},attributes:{style:"text-align:center;"}},
```

I´m getting data from my server so my goal is for the checkbox to be dynamic. When i´m inserting, everything works as expected, if i check the checkbox, in my server appears 1 (TRUE) and 0(FALSE).

My first problem is, **ALL of my other fields appear check too** which is wrong.

My second problem is, when i want to edit, ALL the checkboxes disapear, not the box itself but the check part.

My third problem is, if i simply want to cancel, it throws me an error saying:"Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected number"

Does anyone experience the same type of problems? any help would be most appreciated.

Regards.

Comment: Could you put up an example which reproduces this on the [Telerik Dojo](http://dojo.telerik.com)?

Comment: It´s the same configuration for any table but the fields are boolean and the column as the template, do you know how to perform this?

Comment: You need to change `checked='#= cloud #'` to `#= cloud ? 'checked' : '' #`, because in HTML, if the `checked` attribute exists on an element, the value doesn't matter, it's considered checked. If it's absent, it's unchecked.

Comment: I also don't think you're using `data-bind` correctly, but again, you should put up an example of this if anyone is going to be able to help you.